# What is the purpose of Python's property.getter?

Tags: python, new-style-class

Since Python strives for there to be one right way, I'm wondering what the purpose of property.getter is.  In this example WhyMe defines a getter but Other doesn't so I'm wondering what the point of property.getter is over just using property.

```
class WhyMe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 44

    @property
    def val(self):
        print 'I am not called'
        return self._val

    @val.getter # What advantage do I bring?
    def val(self):
        print 'getter called'
        return self._val

class Other(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 44

    @property
    def val(self):
        print 'I AM called'
        return self._val
```

And using them:

```
>>> why = WhyMe()
>>> why.val
getter called
44
>>> other = Other()
>>> other.val
I AM called
44
```

I'm no stranger to properties, I'm just wondering if there is some advantage to making a getter or if was just put there for symmetry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@property` let's you define a whole new property, by defining a getter for that property. The `@original.getter` syntax lets you *override* just the existing getter. There are also `.setter` and `.deleter` decorators, to the other two methods available to a property.

Imagine you subclassing a custom class that is using a property, with both a getter and a setter defined. If you only wanted to override the *getter* of that property but leaving the *setter* in place (or the deleter), using `@BaseClass.original.getter` lets you do that:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @property
...     def spam(self):
...         print 'Foo.spam called'
...         return 'spam'
...     @spam.setter
...     def spam(self, value):
...         print 'Foo.spam.setter called'
...     @property
...     def ham(self):
...         print 'Foo.ham called'
...         return 'ham'
...     @ham.setter
...     def ham(self, value):
...         print 'Foo.ham.setter called'
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     @Foo.spam.getter
...     def spam(self):
...         print 'Bar.spam override'
...         return 'eggs and spam'
...     @property
...     def ham(self):
...         print 'Bar.ham override'
...         return 'eggs and ham'
... 
>>> Bar().spam
Bar.spam override
'eggs and spam'
>>> Bar().spam = 'foo'
Foo.spam.setter called
>>> Bar().ham
Bar.ham override
'eggs and ham'
>>> Bar().ham = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Note that I only replaced the `spam` *getter*, while it's setter was preserved. The `Bar.ham` setter does not exist, I replaced the `Foo.ham` property wholesale.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.  I'm surprised to realize I haven't ever needed to override a property in a subclass in all years I've used python.